# In LibGDX, How to read a URL parameter and pass it to a GWT module

Tags: gwt, libgdx

In LibGDX, How to read a URL parameter and pass it to a GWT module?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the getParameter(String) method, where String is the name of the parameter in your URL:

```
Window.Location.getParameter(String)
```